# htaccess redirect issue redirected many times

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Earlier my website was having http so my htaccess was working fine without any issue. Yesterday I installed SSL certificate and now my website went down and getting lots of error.
I made changes in the .htaccess file so, all request should be https instead of http. Below is .htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.xxx[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.xxx/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_resume\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_resume/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/profile_view\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile_view/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_resume_pdf\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_resume_pdf/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_emp_profile\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_emp_profile/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_job\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_job/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/job_posting_edit\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ job_posting_edit/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/view_job_response\.php\?var1=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view_job_response/%1? [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^view_resume/([0-9]+)$ /view_resume.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(view_resume)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_resume.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^profile_view/([0-9]+)$ /profile_view.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(profile_view)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ profile_view.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^view_resume_pdf/([0-9]+)$ /view_resume_pdf.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(view_resume_pdf)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_resume_pdf.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^view_emp_profile/([0-9]+)$ /view_emp_profile.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(view_emp_profile)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_emp_profile.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^job_posting_edit/([0-9]+)$ /job_posting_edit.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(job_posting_edit)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ job_posting_edit.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^view_job/([0-9]+)$ /view_job.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(view_job)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_job.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^view_job_response/([0-9]+)$ /view_job_response.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(view_job_response)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ view_job_response.php?var1=$2&var2=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^activation/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ activation.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^activation/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ activation.php?code=$1
```

To redirect to https I have added below code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

But it is giving me error like this **website redirect to you many times**.

Comment: Which URL is causing redirect loop?

Comment: @anubhava both are giving me same error. http://www/mydomain or https://www. or https://mydomain

Comment: I copied these rules on my .htaccess and tested on my Apache. I didn't find any redirect loop. Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Nothing in 301/302. Err.Too_Many_Redirects. This is the error i can see in Network tab. Caching is disabled all the time.

Comment: Before `Too_Many_Redirects` it also shows all the 301 or 302 responses it gets from web server. Also try using command like `curl` or `wget` to see exactly what's causing this.